# 'argument' vs 'argumentation'

Tags: differences

McWhorter, J. [PhD  Linguistics (Stanford)](https://americanstudies.columbia.edu/people/john-h-mcwhorter). [*The Language Hoax* (2016)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/006052085X). p. 59 Top.

> IT CAN BE SURPRISING to see how weak the connection is between language structure and people. Readers may justifiably sense an implication at this point in my **argumentation** that language has nothing to do with culture, or at least nothing important or interesting.
>     Nothing could be further from the truth, and before I proceed with my case, I must make clear that I am referring solely to a particular ***argument [I bolded.]*** about language and culture, rather than, say, dismissing the entire field of linguistic anthropology.

1. What'd change, if 'argumentation' overhead were replaced with 'argument'?
2. In general, how does [argumentation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/argumentation)

> the action or process of reasoning systematically in support of an idea, action, or theory.

differ from [argument](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/argument)

> 2[.] A reason or set of reasons given in support of an idea, action or theory

?

Comment: the one leads to the other: argumentation, when complete leads to the argument.

Comment: The example may just be what is known as elegant variation: using near synonyms to avoid actual repetition of one of the words. The two definitions you give also contain the idea that argumentation refers to the whole body of the arguments in the book, whereas argument refers to a particular set of reasons (which from the context in this case the author actually disagrees with).

Comment: What did your dictionaries and thesauruses leave unclear, please? In the context you seem to be asking about an *argument* is the idea put forward by one side or another, while *argumentation* is the process of (usually) two sides contesting their particular arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Argumentation = is the presentation of formal "arguments".

Comment: Please provide a link to a source, namely a dictionary.